# Command Line Data Copy - Windows Setup

Tags: windows

My solid state boot drive just crashed in my laptop and it's my only PC at the moment.

I have a data drive in my laptop as well - so I figured I'd just wipe it and install my OS on it for the time being.

The thing is I have about 5-10 files that I need and are new since my last backup. I am able to boot into Windows 7 Setup from a USB flash drive, and I have an external HDD ready.

My question is: is it possible for me to access data on this disk from a command prompt in windows setup? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't comfortable with the linux LiveCD, the [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) will do the same with Windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you boot the Windows 7 CD, the first screen asks for your language and keyboard layout. The next screen has a `Repair your Computer` option in the lower left corner. Click on that, then choose the Windows Installation from the list (if it finds one), chose an Administrative user, then click on `Command Prompt`

Note the drive letters may be different; you may need to either use `DISKPART`, or type `dir x:`, replacing `x` with each drive letter starting at C:. Make sure you plug in your USB hard drive before you start the computer, otherwise the Repair environment usually doesn't detect it